# Postman collection variables in a collection run

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

I have a line like `pm.collectionVariables.set("blah", jsonData.someField)` in my *Tests* tab for a request.

It sets the collection variable fine if I run the request in the workspace, but not if I run a Collection Run.

That is, when I run the collection as a "Collection Run", the collection variable is not changed. (!)

Is this right?  Do I need to change the variable to be an environment variable?

Comment: Is the request saved before running the Collection? The runner won't pick up the changes if it's not.

Comment: @DannyDainton - Pretty sure I did, but I'll make sure to try again.  One thing that I think helped was just to tick the checkmark to save variables.

Comment: @Guy, when you say _tick the checkmark to save variables_, I guess you mean that in the **Collection Runner** you check **Keep variable values**?

Comment: @henke - This question is a year old, but thanks for getting back.  I can close this question, but I think the answer is yes.